# How would I use purrr to run a simulation multiple time based upon a list of scenarios and a simulation function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I want to use tibble, *df*, a list of scenarios, *myscenarios*, and a simulation function ,*simu*, to create a result tibble with:

1. 25 rows of data (five rows for each scenario)
2. The result data frame should include the following columns: x, n, v, scenario, result

I would like to achieve this using the appropriate purrr function.

The reprex below provides the tibble, a list of five scenarios and the simu function. The current output simply utilizes the simu function against the df tibble.

Would lmap be the correct purrr function to achieve this? If so, would I have to use lmap in conjuction with mutate?

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x= 1:5, 
             n= c("Jim","John","Jane","Jay","Jack"),
             v= 11:15)

myscenarios <- list("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

simu <- function(x, v){
  x * v + sample(1:10, 1)
} 

result <- df %>% 
  mutate(result = simu(x, v))

result
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>       x n         v result
#>   <int> <chr> <int>  <int>
#> 1     1 Jim      11     21
#> 2     2 John     12     34
#> 3     3 Jane     13     49
#> 4     4 Jay      14     66
#> 5     5 Jack     15     85
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: In the post, I don't see the `myscenarios` used in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` of names with `map`, use assign (`:=`) while evaluating (`!!`) to assign the output to the names

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfc(myscenarios, ~ df %>% 
                   transmute(!! .x := simu(x, v))) %>%
      bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
#      x n         v   one   two three  four  five
#  <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1 Jim      11    16    17    20    13    15
#2     2 John     12    29    30    33    26    28
#3     3 Jane     13    44    45    48    41    43
#4     4 Jay      14    61    62    65    58    60
#5     5 Jack     15    80    81    84    77    79
```

---

If there are `list` of functions that correspond to the elements of 'myscenarios', we can loop over both with `map2` and then apply the function (assuming they have the same arguments), on the dataset, return a single column with `transmute` and bind with the original dataset

```
lstfn <- list(simu, simu, simu, simu, simu)
map2_dfc(myscenarios, lstfn, ~ df %>%
         transmute(!! .x := .y(x, v))) %>%
     bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: This does not seem to run the simulation for each of the scenarios in the myscenario list.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor that part is not clear based on the function showed. Can you expain the values in 'myscenarios' and how it is used for the simu function

Comment: I'm looking to run the simulation five different times, and for scenario, name to be a column in the results table. My actual function will perform a different calculation based upon the scenario.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor if it is the column name, I updated the post

Comment: That was an oversight.  It should be. I guess i was unsure how to have the scenarios a list items and function inputs.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor what is your expected output.

Comment: the updated output is perfect, now my question is how would I have to modify the simu function to have a different calculation for each scenario.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor not clear.  You have a single function and it will have the same behavior if it applied to all the loop

Comment: I was hoping I could use something like a case_when inside the function to have different calcs for different scenarios.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that your effort was much appreciated.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor can you update your post.  I don't know about the logic you want to apply for each case.  So, I am at a loss to know what you wanted

Comment: I think you have answered the question. So if I have a function for each scenario I can use a list of functions. Is this what you are saying in your most recent post?

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor if the list of functions correspond to the `myscenarios`, it can be used.  Even the function can be a string name and then we use `match.fun` to get the value for invoking

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful.  I will also look into match.fun. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm trying to add a modification to your code, but have run into some issues with pmap vs map_2 could you take a loot at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65005405/how-do-i-add-a-third-dynamic-list-element-to-my-pmap-dfc-statement