# How do I add a third dynamic list element to my pmap_dfc statement

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following working code that utilizes two lists to produce simulation output:

```
strategy_list <- list("s_Win","s_WinH1", "s_WinH2", "s_WinH1F1", "s_WinH2F2", "s_WinDerEx")
function_list <- list(s_win, s_winH1, s_winH2, s_winH1F1, s_winH2F2, s_winDerEx)
l <- list(strategy_list, function_list)
simulation <- pmap_dfc(l, ~ df %>%
                      transmute(!! .x := .y(entries, skill, field, win_payoff, wager_amt, Winner, exacta_payoff))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

Now I would like to run the simulation at several different skill levels, so I have added a loop and have tried to replace the skill input with i from the loop to create several variations of the simulation:

```
for (i in seq(from = 0.15, to=0.30, by=0.05)){
skill_list <- list(i, i, i, i, i, i)
strategy_list <- list("s_Win","s_WinH1", "s_WinH2", "s_WinH1F1", "s_WinH2F2", "s_WinDerEx")
function_list <- list(s_win, s_winH1, s_winH2, s_winH1F1, s_winH2F2, s_winDerEx)
l <- list(skill_list, strategy_list, function_list)
simulation <- pmap_dfc(l, ~ df %>%
                      transmute(!! .w !! .x := .y(entries, i, field, win_payoff, wager_amt, Winner, exacta_payoff))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
}
```

Unfortunately, this is producing an error.  I have tried several variations, but can't seem to get the code to work.

**EDIT:**
Based upon Atem's post below, I have updated my code as follows:

```
for (i in seq(from = 0.15, to=0.30, by=0.05)){
strategy_list <- list("s_Win","s_WinH1", "s_WinH2", "s_WinH1F1", "s_WinH2F2", "s_WinDerEx") %>% stringr::str_c(i)
function_list <- list(s_win, s_winH1, s_winH2, s_winH1F1, s_winH2F2, s_winDerEx)
skill_list <- list(i, i, i, i, i, i)
l <- list(strategy_list, function_list, skill_list)
simulation <- pmap_dfc(l, ~ df %>%
                      transmute(!! ..1 := ..2 (entries, ..3, field, win_payoff, wager_amt, Winner, exacta_payoff))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)  %>%
```

Unfortunately, this is still producing an error. The problem appears to be with ..2 as this does not receive the same syntax highlighting as ..1 and ..3.

**EDIT 2:**
To make this a bit simpler I have put together a simplified version of my question and included a reprex. Simulation1 with two lists works fine. Simulation2 with three lists and the loop fails with the error message: could not find function "..2".

````
``` r
library(tidyverse)
z <- 5

df <- tibble(x=1:10, y=1:10)

s_win <- function(x,y,z){
a <-rnorm(x) + x + y + 1 +z
a
}

s_win1 <- function(x,y,z){
b <-  rnorm(x) + x + y + 2 + z
b
}

s_win2 <- function(x,y,z){
c <-  rnorm(x) + x + y + 3 +z
c
}

# Simulation1 with two list works.  

strategy_list <- list("s_Win","s_Win1", "s_Win2") 
function_list <- list(s_win, s_win1, s_win2)
l <- list(strategy_list, function_list)
simulation1 <- pmap_dfc(l, ~ df %>%
                      transmute(!! .x := .y (x, y, z))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)  %>% 
  pivot_longer(
   cols = starts_with("s_"),
   names_to = "Strategy",
   names_prefix = "s_",
   values_to = "Value",
   values_drop_na = TRUE
 ) 
    
View(simulation1)


# Simulation 2 with thre list does not work.  Error message = could not find function "..2"

for (i in seq(from = 5, to=20, by=5)){
strategy_list <- list("s_Win","s_Win1", "s_Win2") %>% stringr::str_c(i)
function_list <- list(s_win, s_win1, s_win2)
skill_list <- list(i, i, i)
l <- list(strategy_list, function_list, skill_list)
simulation2 <- pmap_dfc(l, ~ df %>%
                      transmute(!! ..1 := ..2 (x, y, ..3))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)  %>% 
  pivot_longer(
   cols = starts_with("s_"),
   names_to = "Strategy",
   names_prefix = "s_",
   values_to = "Value",
   values_drop_na = TRUE
 )
}
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `s_Win5`.
#> x could not find function "..2"
#> i Input `s_Win5` is `..2(x, y, ..3)`.
View(simulation2)  
#> Error in as.data.frame(x): object 'simulation2' not found
```
````

<sup>Created on 2020-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve by doing this `!! .w !! .x`?

Comment: @ekoam in the first version using !! .x cause the Strategy to be a column in the data frame. In the second I was hoping to include i and Strategy in columns of the data frame.

Comment: @ekoam - use assign (:=) while evaluating (!!) to assign the output to the names

Comment: Sure. But what is `.w` specifically? Note that purrr-style function shorthands only allow `.x`, `.y`, `.`, `..1`, `..2`, and so on.

Comment: @ekoam .w is supposed to be the first (newly added list) that is the loop variable i that I want to include.  See the skill_list(i,i,i,i,i,i)

Comment: So you want the output column to be something like `0.15s_Win`?

Comment: @ekoam I was going for two separate columns if possible but what you propose would work too.  I guess I don't understand what ths bang bang (!!) operator is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names are stored in `strategy_list`, which is where you will want to incorporate `i`:

```
strategy_list <- list("s_Win","s_WinH1", "s_WinH2",
                      "s_WinH1F1", "s_WinH2F2", "s_WinDerEx") %>% 
                   stringr::str_c(i)
```

Because you now have three lists in `l`, you will also want to switch to using `..1`, `..2`, etc. instead of `.x` and `.y` (which are only appropriate for two sets of arguments):

```
simulation <- pmap_dfc(l, ~ df %>%
                      transmute(!! ..1 := rlang::exec(..2, entries, ..3, field, win_payoff, 
                                              wager_amt, Winner, exacta_payoff))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

**Minor note**: The `!!` operator is known as "unquoting". Without it, `transmute` would create a column called `.x` instead of using the names stored **in** `.x`. Here's an example that demonstrates the difference:

```
x <- "result"
mtcars %>% transmute( x = "Hello World" )
#              x
# 1  Hello World
# 2  Hello World
# ...

mtcars %>% transmute( !!x := "Hello World" )
#         result
# 1  Hello World
# 2  Hello World
# ...
```

**EDIT to address the `..2` issue:** For some reason, `pmap` has issues with interpreting `..2` as containing a function. A simple workaround is to use `rlang::exec` to execute that function with the given arguments:

```
simulation2 <- pmap_dfc(l, ~ df %>%
                      transmute(!! ..1 := rlang::exec(..2, x, y, ..3))) %>%
    # ... as before
```

I updated the original answer above as well.

Comment: thank you for your input. I was focused on using the new list in the column and totally overlooked using ..3 instead of i in the function.   Thanks for your help also appreciate the note on bang bang operator.

Comment: I've rewritten my code as follow, but I still get an error: 
strategy_list <- list("s_Win","s_WinH1", "s_WinH2", "s_WinH1F1", "s_WinH2F2", "s_WinDerEx") %>% str_c(i)
function_list <- list(s_win, s_winH1, s_winH2, s_winH1F1, s_winH2F2, s_winDerEx)
skill_list <- list(i, i, i, i, i, i)
l <- list(strategy_list, function_list, skill_list)
simulation <- pmap_dfc(l, ~ df %>%
                      transmute(!! ..1  := ..2 (entries, ..3, field, win_payoff, wager_amt, Winner, exacta_payoff))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)   doesn't like the ..2 as is not highlighted like others.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor It's a bit difficult to work with your example. I can't reproduce your error since I don't have access to the functions stored in `function_list` or the data in `df`. Would you mind composing a smaller example of the issue? Maybe something with just a couple of simple functions / names.

Comment: sure I will try to put something together.

Comment: I have followed your good advice and provided a simplified version of my question with a reprex. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor Thank you for a very nice reprex. It looks like an issue with `pmap`. Please see my edit for a workaround.